# Rank of a matrix with missing entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

Let $M$ be a $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix over real number field, where the rows and columns are indexed by subsets of $[n] := \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and defined as follows,
$
M_{A, B} = 1
$
if $A \subseteq B$;
$M_{A, B} = -1$
if $B \subsetneq A$;
$M_{A, B}$ can take arbitrary value over $\mathbb{R}$.

In words, $M$ is a matrix with some missing entries. Is there some result lower bounds the rank of matrix $M$, for example, $rk(M) \ge n^{\Omega(\log n)}$.

Comment: What does "undefined" mean? Do you need the lower bound for all matrices with some prescribed values?

Comment: "undefined" = could take any value. Lower bound means the lower bound for all such matrices

Comment: Do you have constructions that allow reducing the rank so much??

Comment: (it seems to be easy to reduce the rank $2^{n/2}$, but one needs something more clever to reduce it even further...)

Comment: I think I have constructions achieving this bound. But I don't know how to prove the lower bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazingly (to me) the rank can be as low as $n$. Simply define $M_{A,B}=1$ when $|A| \le |B|$ and $M_{A,B}=-1$ when $|A| \gt |B|.$ This is consistent with the previous requirements and makes the $A$ row depend only on $|A|.$